# how to get value in for loop from itererator object in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, iterator, generator

In R, I created a iterator using iter function. And I would like to get the values in for Loop.

```
>library("iterators")
> Vector_val = c(0,-2,3,1,5,6,-2,0)
> series = iter(Vector_val)
> for (i in series){
>    print (i)
>    }
```

I can get single values using "nextElem(series)" command but my expcted Output is like this

```
0
-2 
3 
1 
5 
6
-2 
0
```

I'm looking for the solution thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not iterating over the vector itself?

Comment: it does not a matter, my data was in Array. Even if I Change vector into iterator it also won't work

Comment: Based on the code, it is a `vector`

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `sapply`

```
sapply(Vector_val, function(x) nextElem(iter(x)))
#[1]  0 -2  3  1  5  6 -2  0
```

Or if we need only to `print`

```
for(v in Vector_val) print(nextElem(iter(v)))
#[1] 0
#[1] -2
#[1] 3
#[1] 1
#[1] 5
#[1] 6
#[1] -2
#[1] 0
```